# Entering data in one test object enters value on another test object in katalon studio

Tags: katalon-studio

I am trying to enter values in a form . But entering value in one test object executes value in another test object. 
For e.g. Entering "3213213" in input_Phone_form-control, enters value in input_Location_form-control

here is the generated [image]script:

```
WebUI.openBrowser('')

WebUI.navigateToUrl('https://api-dev-new.eeposit.com/openseed/#/')

WebUI.setText(findTestObject('Object Repository/Page_Open Seed/input_LOG IN_form-control'), 'info@eeposit.com')

WebUI.setEncryptedText(findTestObject('Page_Open Seed/input_LOG IN_form-control'), '9G0Ij+ZUwmw=')

WebUI.click(findTestObject('Page_Open Seed/button_LOG IN'), FailureHandling.STOP_ON_FAILURE)

WebUI.click(findTestObject('Object Repository/Page_Open Seed/button_Add New Company'))

WebUI.setText(findTestObject('Object Repository/Page_Open Seed/input_Company Name_form-control'), 'company private limited')

WebUI.setText(findTestObject('Page_Open Seed/input_Location_form-control'), 'Florida')

WebUI.setText(findTestObject('Page_Open Seed/input_Phone_form-control'), '3213213')

WebUI.setText(findTestObject('Page_Open Seed/input_Email_form-control'), 'test@email.com' )

WebUI.click(findTestObject('Object Repository/Page_Open Seed/button_Save Company'))
```

Comment: Please, show us how are `'Page_Open Seed/input_Phone_form-control'` and `'Page_Open Seed/input_Location_form-control'` defined in the Object Repository (double-click them in the OR and copy text from Selector Editor).

Answer (score 0):

This happens, when more than one UI elements has the same identifiers. You need to check input_Phone_form-control and input_Location_form-control objects and set `Detect object by` options.
[image: detect object by]